# android game: how to approach mutliplayer

Tags: android, multiplayer

I'm making a single player game that is near completion, and I am already starting to think about giving the game multiplayer.  The multiplayer would basically be finding someone to play against, likely in a waiting room or just have a match-making function, and then having a pokemon style battle between the people in real time.  I think it would be relatively simple as I'm just sending information about each attack(move chosen and damage) and what it did back and forth, but I'm not sure what resources to consult for this.  I am very new to Android/Java development and really just learning as I go.

I have heard a bit about Skiller, but I'm still unfamiliar with using other SDK's and how easy it may be.  Does anyone have any suggestions as to what SDK's or methods for accomplishing this.  I currently have no money to spend on software development, but I'd like to get started on learning how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't discourage attempting it but even simple multiplayer is a bit involved..

> I think it would be relatively simple as...

Realtime vs. Turn Based multiplayer are very different beasts. Matchmaking would require a publicly accessible ip address so you would need to use a service or host your own. There are issues with NAT traversal, firewalls, etc. Stick with something fast like UDP, keep your messages lightweight and try not to get too chatty.

I'm not sure what advice to give you regarding retrofitting for something like multiplayer once your game is done. Honestly, I can't even imagine the task given how much the game mechanics/flow would require some forethought up front. You have to think very differently when you don't know when/if a message will arrive?